# Copying Excel data into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to copy some data from excel(part numbers) into NEO4J to analyze clicks. I had to use some formulas to clean the data (concatenate and add quotes), but NEO4J is not recognizing the text. However, if I take the same part numbers and manually type them in, it returns a value as normal.

Does anyone know a workaround?

My excel data( I want to copy the comma seperated text):
[image]

Comment: By "excel data", do you mean a CSV file? Can you show the contents of the actual file?

Comment: Also, can you show the code that you have already tried?